# HTML- how to display spans as a list with no <br>?

Tags: html, list

I have to create a div with some spans. The spans  should be display  in a list (the profile-tool-tip span and the text light span).

I used a `<br>` for that. The problem is that the last span, the text light, is in the padding instead above it).

How can I fix it?

```
<span class="flex">
    <span class="profile-tool-tip " url="/threebaysover/profile/companyProfileTooltip/NA%3D%3D"><a href="/threebaysover/profile/show/NA%3D%3D">Wow</a></span>
    <span class="text-light">
        has added 4 new photos to the product  -
        <a href="/threebaysover/product/show/Mg%3D%3D">wow tour</a>
    </span>

    <span class="text-light">
        <br>
        · 51 minutes ago
    </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to have `span`s each on own line without using `br`, you can declare them as block.

```
span.flex span {display: block;} /* or list-item if you need really a list */
```

Comment: @panther- it doesn't do the job. The span of the time is directly after the "has added 4 new photos to the product " (inline) instesd below it

Comment: So you make probably st. bad. When you use `display: block;`, it can´t be inline :-)  http://jsfiddle.net/jz5tmk0h/

Comment: @panther-u are right. I put the style the wrong place. 10x